# Why is variable array-length in a function-call possible in C but not in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, variables, parameters, size

I would like to treat an flat 1D Array inside a function as it was a 3D array. I know I can use a macro to translate coordinates like that:

```
#define f3d(x,y,z,nx,ny) ( (z)*(nx)*(ny) + (y)*(nx) + (x))
```

But my teacher told me there is a way to simply cast them in the function call.
So the following test program is working perfectly good with compiler call: `gcc -std=c99 -o test.exe main.c`

main.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
static void init(int n, double a[n][n][n]){  
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
      for(int k=0; k<n; k++)
        a[i][j][k] = i;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  int n = 5;
  double *a = malloc(n*n*n*sizeof(*a));
  init(n, (double (*)[n][n])a);
  for(int i=0; i<n*n*n; i++)printf("%lf ",a[i]);    
  return 0;
}
```

But now I have to use C++ and I can't compile it with:  `g++ -o test.exe main.c` 
Compiler says `error: array bound is not an integer constant`
I can imagine why compilers struggle with variable arraylengths, but why is it working in C ?

Can somebody tell me why?

And is there a workaround for this problem?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:
Thanks a lot for the Answers, but now I'm confused. I use g++ (SUSE Linux) 4.4.1 [gcc-4_4-branch revision 150839] which should be capable of VLAs. Why is it not compiling and throws "error: array bound is not an integer constant"  ?

Comment: C supports VLAs; C++ does not. I'm sure someone will pull out the standard with the proof.

Comment: The solution for C++ would be to use an STL vector instead

Comment: Not sure if to answer or comment, however this code is illegal in C. a should be declared as `double (*a)[n][n]`. You are not allowed to cast a pointer to double to a pointer to array of array of double.

Answer (score 2):

From GCC:

> http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html
>
> Variable-length automatic arrays are allowed in ISO C99, and as an
>   extension GCC accepts them in C90 mode and in C++. These arrays are
>   declared like any other automatic arrays, but with a length that is
>   not a constant expression. The storage is allocated at the point of
>   declaration and deallocated when the brace-level is exited.
>   ...
>
> You can also use variable-length arrays as arguments to functions:
>
> ```
>  struct entry
>  tester (int len, char data[len][len])
>  {
>    /* ... */
>  }
> ```

Comment: That code doesn't have a "variable-length automatic array", it has a "pointer to variable length array" type.

Comment: Also an optional feature of C11.